# Chrome desktop shortcut not working after renaming chrome.exe

Tags: windows-8, google-chrome, shortcuts

```
Chrome Version : Google Chrome        31.0.1650.57 (Official Build 235101) m
Operating System : Windows 8
Extensions : AdBlock 2.6.14, Any.do 0.1.1.1, avast! Online Security 9.0.2005.45, Awesome Screenshot: Capture & Annotate 3.5.2, Evernote Web Clipper 6.0.3, Google Dictionary (by Google) 3.0.19, LastPass 3.0.14, The Times of India 1.0.4, WOT 2.3.1
```

Since the last few days I had not been able to surf any page on Chrome, I could not even open the "setting" page nor any other option on the Wrench section. Whatever I tried to open the result was just a blank page with no activity at all. I tried all sorts of different solutions listed on the various sites like reinstalling, disabling/uninstalling my AV/firewall, scanning for possible malware, etc., but nothing worked.

The only thing that worked was renaming the Chrome executable (in `C:/Program Files/Google/Chrome/Application`) to something else other than the default `chrome.exe`. However, now all my shortcuts have stopped working. I have tried recreating these with the renamed file, but to no avail. I always keep getting the same error, see screenshot below.

Is there any way to get the shortcuts working? I'm presuming there would be some registry changes required.

[image: screenshot of Chrome's error]

Answer (score 0):

To make your shortcut working,right click on shortcut -->short cut Tab
Now change the `target` to location of original executable name.

[image: Chrome]

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering! I have already tried that. The shortcut works for few minutes then it reverts back to giving an error.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering! I have already tried that. The shortcut works for few minutes then it starts giving the same error. Note that the shortcut still points to the renamed file when the error occurs

Comment: strange...check whether your system is virus infected.